# Até que ponto deve-se utilizar snippets?

Tags: front-end

São uma *mão na roda*, no entanto, me sinto **culpado** por não exercer o trabalho braçal esperado.

Portanto, quero a **opinião de vocês** para saber **quando** e até que **ponto** um Front-ender deve usar snippets.

Comment: snippet? Do github?

Comment: Github, bootstrap, próprios ou etc. Relamente, não me importa a fonte.

Comment: Snippets no github (aka [gist](https://gist.github.com/)) são ferramentas para compartilhar conhecimento. Devem ser usadas para tal fim

Comment: As linguagens e ferramentas são criadas justamente para evitar trabalho braçal desnecessário. Lembre-se que qualidade do projeto não é medida em número de linhas que você digita, mas sim na qualidade do código. Se as ferramentas fazem o trabalho bem feito, não tem porque não usar. A questão é: você entende exatamente aquilo que a ferramenta faz? Um erro muito comum de iniciantes é justamente ficar dependente das ferramentas e não dominar o básico.

Comment: João 90% das dúvidas de Bootstrap que vejo por aqui é gente que copiou e colou o Snippet de qq jeito e nem sabe direito o que está fazendo... Tem muita gente que pega o Snippet aqui do StackOverflow tb sem entender o que está fazendo. Isso realmente é condenável. Mas se vc usa apenas para poupar tempo e sabe para que serve e como aplicar cada um deles ai eu não vejo problema. Inclusive eu mesmo crio meus Snippets pelo *VS Code* Olha aqui pre vc entender https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets

Comment: Link com uma conversa sobre o assunto https://dev.to/botherchou/code-snippets-or-nah-5m9

Comment: @hugocsl Obrigado, pelo link!

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss De fato, não domino algumas tecnologias, por completo. Desse jeito, começarei a pensar em utilizar menos snippets.